# Font installation working on Win/miktex but not Ubuntu/texlive

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing, texlive

after researching and trying out many tipps here from online ressources (spending two days) I am about to give up - but still hope that maybe you might have some good idea.

The task: I want to install the rotis font package. I've got both the font files themselves as well as the help files from CTAN following also the instructions included there (http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/pro.txt).
Unfortunately the routine for TeX Live (2009) is not described, but I thought I found my way using different other ressources.

What have I done/tried so far?

- Using kpsewhich TEXMFLOCAL / TEXMFHOME / pdftex.map etc to identify visible paths/locations.
- Copying all relevant files to their respective locations and TEXMFLOCAL
- I checked, that no local (`~/texmf` `~/.texmf-var` etc.) might interact
- texhash (many times)
- Using `updmap-sys --enable Map=pro.map`
- Checked whether the entries for the font are included in the pdftex.map file identified with kpsewhich -> the entries are there!

Hopefully I have not forgotten anything.

As I have a dual boot installation I tried the installation also under Windows / MikTeX 2.9 - I managed to install the fonts within one hour!

Thus, using the exact same testfile that worked under miktex under TeXLive09/Ubuntu12.04 I got the following error:

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/pro/t1pro.fd)
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/pro/t1pr1.fd) 
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] 
(./Fonttest1.aux) )
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}
{/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file pr1r8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help (and questions)!

Comment: Did you do steps 4 and 5 above using `sudo`?

Comment: Initially not, but throughout the process I applied these commands with sudo.

Comment: did you check the case of the file names? Cases does not matter on Windows. What does `kpsewhich pr1r8r.pfb` say?

Comment: pdflatex can't find a type font: `pr1r8a.pfb`. Does it exits? It is in the right place? Did you update the file database?

Comment: Dear Daleif, thank you for the hint. Indeed I installed the font files initially with wrong (upper) case. Before I posed the question I manually changed them to lower case, problem persisted. But now that you mentioned it, I finally repeated again step 4 and 5 above. Although $kpsewhich pr1r8r.pfb$ still doesn't show any results - it now works! Thank you very much for this important hint! What shall I do to close the question?

Comment: Dear Ulrike, thank you. kpsewhich pr1r8a.pfb brings now the respective code!